# How does this obfuscated hello world program using non-printable unicode characters work

Tags: ruby

A [cartoon](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/) has [this hello world program](https://gist.github.com/qrohlf/7045823) as an example of Ruby code.

The code looks like this; but has a number of non-printable unicode characters that I can't get into the Stack Overflow code editor.

```
      = 1
      =  + 
      =   *  + 
      =    *  
      = 
      [      *(   +  )+  , 
             =     *    + , 
             =     *    +    -  , 
            , 
            =        +    ,
        *  +    +  , 
        *    -  *    +   +  , 
           , 
           + +  , 
            , 
        *    ,     + +  , 
        ]
puts      .map(&:chr).join
```

I wanted to see how it worked, but when I initially tried running it in several online IDEs, they all reported syntax errors because GitHub didn't put the unicode chars in the web version.  Anyone trying to copy the code from here or the GitHub page instead of downloading the zip version (to get the special characters) will have the same problem. Having figured out the problem with getting it to run, how does it work?

Comment: No way I'm running this. :)

Comment: It is very likely that the original code is full of invisible unicode characters that were lost somewhere on the way into your ide. And they are sure to be absent here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev WOW!  That certainly is a level of WTF beyond what I was expecting.  Both in terms of trying to see it run without having Ruby installed locally; and in puzzling out what it's doing.

Comment: Hmm.  Copying from a downloaded zip file into ideone, got the code to run there (and showed all the hidden unicode); but the SO editor seems to be eating them since i still can't paste it into here.

Comment: Opening the file in a hex editor doesn't show anything obvious (my first thought, the nonprintables hiding something else if coerced into ASCII didn't hold water).

Comment: Reminder to self: vote to reopen if this gets closed. Losing invisible ubicode characters when copying and pasting into SO is not a "simple typographical error."

Comment: @KyleStrand Hopefully my edit will head off the close attempt; knowing how/why it's working is my main curiosity.

Comment: @KyleStrand: but it's still "can't be reproduced", so it's not answerable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The original code works if you get all the unicode in; not being able to have the working code in the question itself appears to be a problem with the SO code editor.  Working example in  [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/aXcT34)

Comment: I asked about the code editor problem on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271859/unable-to-copy-unprintable-unicode-characters-into-the-code-editor).  If I get an explanation of how to do so, I'll edit this question to include the complete obfuscated code instead of just the visible part.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure it's reproducible; just follow the steps OP mentions (copy code directly from Git into an online Ruby interpreter, e.g. [repl.it](https://repl.it/Ba06/0)).

Comment: @KyleStrand: Ah, the zip download.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the zipped file, a character that resembles an underscore is used. Replacing those characters with an underscore does not change the program's behavior, so I will do so here:

```
_     = 1
__    = _+_
___   = __*__+_
____  = ___*__
_____ = 
      [____  *(___+__)+__, 
    _______  = ____*____+_, 
    ________ = ____*____+____-__, 
    ________, 
    _______ = _______+____,
    ____*__+____+__, 
    ____*____-__*____+___+__, 
    _______, 
    _______+_+__, 
    ________, 
    ____*____, ____+_+__, 
    ____]
puts _____.map(&:chr).join
```

Notice that sequences of one to eight (excluding six) `_` are used as different variables, so let's replace them with `a`, `b`, ... `h` (excluding `f`) to make them easier to read:

```
a     = 1
b    = a+a
c   = b*b+a
d  = c*b
e = 
      [d  *(c+b)+b, 
    g  = d*d+a, 
    h = d*d+d-b, 
    h, 
    g = g+d,
    d*b+d+b, 
    d*d-b*d+c+b, 
    g, 
    g+a+b, 
    h, 
    d*d, d+a+b, 
    d]
puts e.map(&:chr).join
```

After usual formatting, you get:

```
a = 1
b = a + a
c = b * b + a
d = c * b
e = [
  d * (c + b) + b,
  g = d * d + a,
  h = d * d + d - b,
  h,
  g = g + d,
  d * b + d + b,
  d * d - b * d + c + b,
  g,
  g + a + b,
  h,
  d * d,
  d + a + b,
  d
]
puts e.map(&:chr).join
```

It all starts with `a = 1`, and eventually defines the array `e`, which is:

```
e # => [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 13, 10]
```

And each of its element is the ASCII code of character in `"Hello World\r\n"`. By applying `chr` to that number, you get:

```
["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d", "\r", "\n"]
```

and when you `join` them and `puts`, you get the output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: The “character that resembles an underscore” appears to be [`U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) (I guess your editor is adding the underlines so you can see the characters are there). Strangely this seems to be a valid character for a local variable–in fact a quick test suggests that Ruby will accept many (if not all) of the unicode space characters as valid variables names. Possibly a Ruby bug?

Comment: @matt No it is not. That is the usual case. Different natural languages occasionally have additional white space characters, and handling all of them across languages as white space characters would be a mess. I used emacs, by the way.

Comment: @sawa Which `zipped file` are you referring? The zip file option in `gist` page?

Comment: @WandMaker I got the file directly into Ruby using `require 'open-uri'; s = open("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/qrohlf/7045823/raw/62872dc449eb9e330df146cc2d49050da853ae4d/helloworld").read`. (The url is from the “Raw” link on the gist page). From there you can examine the string with e.g. `s.bytes`, `s.chars` etc.

Comment: @sawa Ruby could at least treat the [25 characters listed by Wikipedia as "whitespace characters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) as whitespace-only characters. `U+00A0` is indeed on the list.

Comment: This [discussion about the `.strip()` function](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7845) seems relevant--some versions of Ruby apparently treat `U+00A0` as whitespace (for text processing purposes, not for source-file parsing), while others do not. Matz seems open to the idea of treating these non-ASCII whitespace characters as whitespace for the purpose of text-processing, and I don't think that's too different from treating them as whitespace for the purpose of source-file parsing.

Comment: @KyleStrand in my quick testing, I found Ruby also allows things like C1 control characters, private use area characters, members of the Unicode Specials block and bidirectional text control characters as local variables. It looks like currently anything over 128 that is a valid character is allowed. In order to fix this, you would probably have to make the Unicode database available to the parser, which I imagine could be a challenge.

Comment: @matt If you're willing to go big hammer instead of elegant, a standalone pass with a unicode validator could do the job without making significant changes to the build process.